# MS Project Gantt chart control usage in C#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, controls, ms-project, gantt-chart

Has anybody used the MS Project Gantt chart control in C#?
If yes, can you share some resources regarding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also check [Gantt Chart Library](http://DlhSoft.com/GanttChart) for WPF or Windows Forms, they do not require Microsoft Project installed on the client computer, but provide similar UI for project and related Gantt Charts.

Answer (score 1):

Try these links for a start.

http://www.ilog.com/products/ganttnet/

http://www.netronic.com/products-for-developers/gantt-charts.html?gclid=COLdutasoZUCFQunQwodoWOPkw

Comment: Netronic make you register on their site just to see a price list - FAIL

Answer (score 0):

My company decided to buy the Infragistics NetAdvantage for .NET. We will be using their Gantt control.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for simple Gantt Chart control in asp.net i recommend jsGantt.It's purely written in javascript  ript,html,css and very fast.Also easy to integrate with any of the language in web. Here is a good tutorial of using  jsGantt in ASP.net Here in [CodeGlobe](http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-gantt-chart-in-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Microsoft Gantt](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/gantt-chart.aspx) and you want help in developing Gantt Chart application for Microsoft Office Project, you can have help from below link

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/how-to-create-gantt-control-in-wpf.html