# c# best approach for grid similar to MS Project

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I am building an application in C# with Visual Studio 2010. I am looking for the best approach to build a grid very similar to the functionality that is used in MS Project.

Basically: 
  multiple columns
  plus/minus to expand child items
  tab to make current row a child row above

Please let me know if anybody has had to deal with an issue like this before.

Comment: This would be much less painful in WPF...

Comment: It thought about going that route, but I have no experience at all in WPF, so I thought the entire project would go slower that way.

Comment: The benefits of WPF over WinForms are substantial...my vote would be to take the plunge...especially when you are wanting to do heavy UI tasks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Project Gantt chart control usage in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067/ms-project-gantt-chart-control-usage-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a Gantt Chart? Check out this question: [MS Project Gantt chart control usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067/ms-project-gantt-chart-control-usage-in-c)

Comment: The only issue, is that while I want the functionality displayed in the gantt chart grid on the left, I do not need the actual gantt chart on the right. Also, my need for this is very different than project management, and the gantt chart controls I have found seem to focus on project management style data.

Comment: Ok I understand. Are you looking for code samples or for a library that you could use?

Comment: either would work, I looked at the grid in the telerik controls and it may be possible to use that, but that would be the only control I need, and cant really afford 1k for that bit of functionality.

Comment: Do you have a licence for any component yet?

Comment: Nope, do most of my development is done with standard controls.

Comment: Didn't notice the major grammar errors in my last statement, had a phone call in the middle of trying to type, sorry. I do not own any third party controls, but have wanted to buy some, just cant really afford them since 99% of the development I do is for personal use applications, and a little bit for my wife to use to make her job easier.