# Create Gantt Chart in Winfoms C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagridview, visualization

I am trying to create a kind of Gantt Chart in Winfoms (I can consider to do in Wpf) which should display data as the following image:

[image]

Until now I had been try to do it using gridView, which is close to the wanted result but I have not been able to get the vertical line:

[image]

There is any way to have this vertical line over the gridView or even a better way to achieve this desired result (picture 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen these open-source solutions:

[[1]](https://ganttchart.codeplex.com/) &
[[2]](http://www.jakesee.com/net-c-winforms-gantt-chart-control/)

I think it's better not to reinvent the wheel!

More solutions could be as the following:

- [MS Project Gantt chart control usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067/ms-project-gantt-chart-control-usage-in-c-sharp)
- [Gantt Chart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20731/Gantt-Chart)
- [I think this one is not open source](http://radiantq.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Currently I cannot access link 2 and link 1 looks very interesting.  Do you have also other solutions?

Comment: I updated my answer, BTW, If you think my answer has been helpful to you please consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow check mark :)